# What do parentheses do when used after a variable in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This question might be stupid but I don't know Python well enough to know what's going on.
So I was trying to learn TensorFlow and noticed this weird invocation:

```
model = Sequential(
   # ...
)

predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
```

Can someone please explain what `model(x_train[:1])` is doing here? From what I can tell, model is an object that's already constructed above? Is this using the object as a method/function? Or is something else going on here?

Comment: Here `Sequential` is probably a class. You use something like `Sequential()` to define a class object for that class.

Comment: An object is callable if its class defines the special method `__call__`.

Comment: this is just a special quirk of Tensorflow for convenience of doing a forward pass

Comment: that is a *call*. You can call functions, classes, and other "callable" objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the Tensorflow authors have provided an implementation for the `__call__` "magic method" in the `tf.keras.Sequential` class hierarchy.

This allows you to invoke the instance of the object as-if it were a function. The call to `model = Sequential(...)` initialises the class itself via the `__init__` constructor. The `model()` calls into the `__call__` magic method.

Tensorflow and torch use this as convenience wrapper for a forward pass through the network (in most cases).

Comment: It's not exactly the same as a ```predict()``` call.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: Yep, with the direct `predict()` call being useful for larger batches from my understanding.